# How do I fit flow values to connections in a known network?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, terminology, computer-science, network-theory

This is not my area and I'm new to its terminology, and am posting my problem in the hope that someone will be able to direct me to where it has been solved, or who has written about it.

I have a flow network - I'm imagining intersections connected by tubes. I have several sources and sinks. I know the total volume moving through the network, and values for the total flow into and out of each intersection. I am trying to calculate the distribution of 'flow' through each tube given these conditions. The tubes, we imagine, have infinite capacity, and it 'costs' nothing to push flow through them. Is this a solved problem? What is it called?

Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This is called the *feasible flow problem*.  You can use network simplex or any linear programming algorithm to find the flow along each arc subject to a supply/demand constraint at each node.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to help. Please mark my answer as accepted.